# Query for multiple values in a single column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm storing multiple numbers in a MySQL column by using a delimiter like this ("1,5,10"). I didn't know that it's not a good way to store the data, but now I have no choice left.

Anyway, I have a table Like this:

```
MovieID     |     genre
------------------------------------
   1              1,2,3
   2              2,4
   3              1,2
   4              2,5,10
```

I want to filter the movies by the genre ids. Such as, if I search for genre id 1,2, all the movies will be fetched which contain these genre ids.

I have tried:

`AND FIND_IN_SET('".$genre_list."',genre) > 0`

`AND genre IN('".$genre_list."')`

`AND genre LIKE('%".$genre_list."%')`

But nothing worked.

I'm doing like this:

```
function make_query($minimum_rating, $maximum_rating, $category, $country){

    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM videos
    WHERE publication = '1'
    
    ";

    if (isset($minimum_rating, $maximum_rating) && !empty($minimum_rating) && !empty($maximum_rating)) {
        
        $query .= "
        AND imdb_rating BETWEEN '".$minimum_rating."' AND '".$maximum_rating."'          
        ";
    }

    if (isset($category)) {
        // $category_filter = implode("','", $category);

        foreach ($category as $cat){
             
             $query .= "
             AND FIND_IN_SET('$cat', genre) > 0
        ";

        }
       
    }

    if (isset($country)) {
        $country_filter = implode("','", $country);
        $query .= "
        AND country IN('".$country_filter."')
        ";
    }


    return $query;


}
```

It only shows the movies which contain the genres like if the array contains 1,2,3. It fetches the MovieID 1.

My expected outcome was MovieID 1,2,3,4

Comment: What type of variable is `$genre_list`? Have you verified your examples by using values first?

Comment: The duplicate question is about searching for cases where all of the multiple values are found, using `AND`. If you want any of the multiple values to match, then use `OR`, but otherwise it will be a similar solution to the one in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Sam020 Its a string..

Comment: @BillKarwin Please, have a look...I have edited the question based on my scenario.

Comment: You're using `AND` but apparently you want `OR`. I already answered this in my previous comment.

Comment: @BillKarwin Yes, I TRIED...But it didn't work. I also need to concatenate the query with others. How can i do that ? Should i need to use another AND before OR ? Please, take a look the code for last time. I have added the whole function. Hope you will get the idea.

Comment: It helps if you not only show us the PHP, but also the complete SQL you tried. If you get the SQL correct, you will probably have a better understanding of how to put the query together with PHP.

Comment: You have conditions before this already that are joined with AND, so of course you can not _just_ switch all the ANDs you had for your categories with OR now - AND binds stronger than OR, so you would have "connected" your first category condition to all the previous ones via AND, and all the following category conditions would "stand on their own" - _any_ satisfied category condition would then satisfy your _whole_ condition, regardless of all the previous ones. You need to wrap all your OR-joined category conditions into braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RLIKE` for every genre matching.

For example if You want to find rows with genres `1,5` You can run this:

```
select * from videos where genre RLIKE '^1$|^1,|,1$|,1,' AND genre RLIKE '^5$|^5,|,5$|,5,';
```

Comment: Its not gonna work for me. Because,i have genre like this 1,2,3,11,22,33......So when i search for 1 or 2 ...it gonna fetch 1,2,11,22...which is not accurate.

Comment: Here...I think FIND_IN_SET will do my work...but i need to use OR instead of AND.....I'm confused...how can i concatenate the query with others ?